# NoMethodError: undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass while running Ruby Rspec on gets.chomp

Tags: ruby, rspec

This is my first post here. I'm fairly new to Ruby, especially RSpec and have been running into an issue. I have written a method that uses gets.chomp to receive a player input. However I have this method called in another method

```
def prompt_move
        loop do     
            @move = gets.chomp.to_i 
            return move if valid_move?(move)                    
            puts "Invalid input. Enter a column number between 1 and 7"
        end
    end

    def valid_move?(move)
        @move.is_a?(Integer) && @move.between?(1, 7)
    end

    def play_round
        print_board
        prompt_player
        @move = prompt_move     
    end
```

Here is the code for my RSpec tests:

```
describe ConnectFour do
  subject(:game) { described_class.new }
    let(:player){ double(Player) }

describe '#prompt_move' do      
        context 'move is a valid input' do          
            before do
                allow(game).to receive(:gets).and_return('3\n')
            end
            
            it 'returns move and stops the loop' do
                error_message = 'Invalid input. Enter a column number between 1 and 7'
                expect(game).to_not receive(:puts).with(error_message)              
                game.prompt_move
            end
        end
            
        context 'when given one invalid input, then a valid input' do
            before do
                letter = 'a'
                valid_input = '1'
                allow(game).to receive(:gets).and_return(letter, valid_input)
            end

            it 'completes loop and displays error message once' do                          
                error_message = 'Invalid input. Enter a column number between 1 and 7'              
                expect(game).to receive(:puts).with(error_message).once             
                game.prompt_move
            end
        end
    end
```

If I remove the #prompt_move method from #play_round the tests pass without any issue. However when I try to call it from within #play_round it gives me
NoMethodError:
undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass

I have been struggling to figure out what is causing this error so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question and post the rest of the code relevant to this problem. The code you have posted will not run as `game` is not defined in your test code and neither is `move` in your `prompt_move` method. Does `game` refers to an instance of the class your methods are defined in? I note you are stubbing a `gets` method on `game`. Did you mean to stub `Kernel#gets`? This is likely the cause of the error you are seeing. Also, your `valid_move?` method currently ignores its argument, did you mean to do a comparison on `move` instead of the instance variable `@move`?

Comment: game is referring to the ConnectFour class, which I just put in an edit. I'm not sure what Kernel#gets is exactly...

Comment: @MatzFan `Kernel#gets` is available as a private method on all objects, so, at a glance, this looks like it should have worked.

Comment: @BESteffen82: you want double quotes in `'3\n'`, btw.

Comment: After I fixed a couple typos (`move` vs `@move`) it Works For Me™. https://gist.github.com/schwern/69a8dc82bebf6353265963a4abc8dd16  We'll need a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: For some reason i'm still getting the error even after running the updated code that @Schwern posted

Comment: @BESteffen82 What versions of rspec, rspec-mocks, and Ruby?

Comment: i'm running Ruby 3.0.3, rspec 3.11, rspec-mocks 3.11.1

Comment: Just to make sure, what line is the error coming from?

Comment: It would be line 4 in your code. The "@move = gets.chomp.to_i" line

Comment: @BESteffen82 Tried with the same versions, Works For Me™. You're just pasting my code into a file and `rspec thatfile`? Nothing weird in your rspec config?

Comment: Also note that `'3\n'.chomp` gives "3\\n", although this is still coerced to 3 by `String#to_i`. Should be `"3\n"`

Comment: Yea. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @BESteffen82 Don't leave us hanging, what was the issue? Perhaps you can self-answer.

Comment: Nevermind. Its not working again. So i have other code in this file that I didn't include in this question. When I run rspec on just your code it works fine so something else in the rest of the code must be throwing the error

Comment: Here is the full code I have so far: https://github.com/BESteffen82/connect_four/blob/main/lib/connect_four.rb

Comment: @BESteffen82 Is `new_game = ConnectFour.new;
new_game.play_game` in the class file you are testing?

Comment: They are not. So i just took them out of the file. Now all the tests are passing like they should be so it looks like that was the issue. Why would having them in there cause the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're executing code in your class file.

```
new_game = ConnectFour.new
new_game.play_game
```

This will run every time you load the file, like when you're testing it. It will prompt for input and run `gets`. What it's getting is the code of the test file (for some rspec reason). That's invalid, so it keeps running `gets` until eventually there is no more input and `gets` returns `nil`.

Remove that from your class file. Code like that should be in a separate file which requires the class.